# Why i can not use bootstrap Glyphicons in my text box?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I'm new in bootstrap and want to use Glyphicons in my text box,for that purpose write this code:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="نام">
    </div>
```

but when i run my page can not see any icon in text box,how can i solve that?thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
I hope this will helps you.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm0-offset-4">
   <div class="form-group has-feedback">
     <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess2">Input with Icon</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess2">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```